# Why this error appeared "No module named fsspec " and before it was working well

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I am using pandas to read from gcs buckets and after making the required transformation and want to save it as parquet i got this error `No module named fsspec`, I solved it by just installing fsspec,gcsfs libraries but I just want to know why this error appeared and before it was running well.

`I installed two libraries (fsspec,gcsfs) and works well but I want to know what the reason behind this error`

Comment: I use pandas to make transform for some files and after that, I save the final file at Gcs Bucket. the code was working well but unfortunately at a day the pipeline is failed and  need to install two libraries (fsspec,gcsfs), I installed them and it became works well but I don't know what exactly happened to need these libraries and it was working well before.

Answer (score 2):

I had to install too

```
pip3 install fsspec gcsfs
```

I know it is already in the answer but this is what helped me.

I suppose that under the hood, when Pandas is interacting with GCS, requires these 2 libraries to interact with this service.